# Xcode 4 will no longer run apps on 4.2.10 device (CDMA iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Up until today, I have been able to test my app on my CDMA iPhone, running 4.2.10.  I am building against the 4.3 SDK, with a deployment target of 4.0.

After restarting my phone today, Xcode will no longer allow me to test the app on my phone, with this message in the Organizer window: "The version of iOS on "iPhone" does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.  Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK"

Unfortunately there are some bugs with location services in the simulator, so I can't use that for testing either.

Can I even install the 4.2 SDK in Xcode 4?  Is anyone else having this problem, or (hopefully) does anyone know how to fix it?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install xcode 4 it will actually gather the build chain from your phone and use it for compiling. You can see this in the organizer window (Window->Organizer?).

Answer (score 2):

You know I had that same issue i found that I had to download the latest xcode and reinstall because for some reason the ios that came with xcode knew how to build on my phone. Sorry man.